# Copy file from one container to another container in Azure Data Lake 2 programatically

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a storage account from type ADLS Gen2, with 2 containers.
I would like to copy a blob file from container A to container B, with java SDK.
I'm using `DataLakeFileSystemClient` and I'm looking for something like the `rename` method of `DataLakeFileClient` which supports renaming to other container.

Heres the example of rename I did:

```
private DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient;

public boolean rename(String source, String target, String targetContainer) {
    DataLakeFileClient dataLakeFileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient(source).rename(targetContainer, target);
    return dataLakeFileClient.exists();
}
```

But I'm looking for only copying and not moving, Thanks.

Comment: We can use Azure blob rest api to manage Azure Data Lake 2. So we can azure blob copy api to copy the file. For more details, please refer to here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#blob-storage-apis